# Given $10$ firecrackers, of which $4$ are defective, what is the probability of randomly drawing (with replacement) $3$ defective ones?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Can someone please verify the answer to this very simple question?

> A packet contains $10$ distinguishable firecrackers out of which $4$ are defective. If $3$ firecrackers are drawn at random (*With Replacement*) from the packet, then what is the probability that all $3$ firecrackers are defective?

My answer is $\left(\dfrac{4}{10}\right)^3$ because there are essentially 3 bernoulli trials with probability of success equal to $\dfrac{4}{10}$. and we are being asked  "what is the probability that all 3 trials result in sucesses"

> Can someone please verify if this answer is correct?

Comment: It would be a helpful exercise for you to include in your post why you think that's the correct answer.

Comment: It is correct, but to make sure you understand the concepts correctly, what would your answer be if two of the firecrackers draw were defective instead of three?

Comment: then the answer would be $\binom{3}{2} \dfrac{4*4*6}{10^3}$. right?

Comment: @abhishek yeah it is right

Comment: thanks @Bulbasaur

Comment: Critical that these *bernoulli* trials represent *independent* events.  Certainly, in the stated problem, each drawing (with replacement) of a firecracker is an independent event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it's correct.

3 firecrackers are drawn at random with replacement.  4 out of 10 in a packet are defective.  the question is what is the probability.

---